# Table joining order in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Could you give advice on correct joining order for tables i.e. for 4 tables combining data which order we have to take into consideration. As I am having problems in running queries and I am getting an `ORA-00904` error:

```
select countries.country_name, profits.amount_sold, products.prod_name
from countries
join customers on countries.country_id = customers.country_id
join profits on products.prod_id = profits.prod_id
join profits on profits.cust_id = customers.cust_id
WHERE COUNTRY_NAME = 'India'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining to the `profits` table twice, and not joining to the `products` table. Looks like you meant it to be:

```
select countries.country_name, profits.amount_sold, products.prod_name
from countries
join customers on countries.country_id = customers.country_id
join profits on profits.cust_id = customers.cust_id
join products on products.prod_id = profits.prod_id
WHERE COUNTRY_NAME = 'India'
```

Oracle will decide the join order, but you can't reference a table before you've joined to it.